# Can't start iphone simulator; "not responding". Xcode 7, simulator version 9 (for iOS 9)

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, simulator

Ever since i updated to the GM version of encode 7 I've been unable to use the simulator. I used to get an error, but when I updated to the official release (through app store) that stopped. Now it says "running [name of app] on iPhone [model]". When I look in the force quit menu it says not responding

When I press "stop" it continues to show the same message. When closed and reopened it says "Build succeeded at... etc.", so I'm quite certain that the problem lies in the simulator and not the copy of xcode.

I've tried projects that worked before, including one that I downloaded from the apple guide (I figured that would have to work if there was some problem with the code in my other projects).

Comment: Did you install separate copy of XCode, or via App Store? I guess reinstalling should fix the problem.

Comment: I have tried both downloading from the Apple developer site (the GM, when it was not yet released), and now the official release from the app store. @iphonic

Comment: I doubt reinstalling will do anything useful.  There is one rare issue where launchd_sim can get into a wedged state where we see it with a single child process, xpcproxy_sim.  Both are idle and end up blocking Simulator.app.  I'd check your running processes, and if you have xpcproxy_sim as the single child of launchd_sim, that's probably what you're seeing.  Sending SIGKILL to launchd_sim (or rebooting) should be enough to get you out of the bad state.

Answer (score 8):

I have  same problem, i just quit all application, and shutdown Mac, and restart it.

And I have my iPhone simulator working fine.

This problem occurs because of unexpected power off of Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem.

Did you try to go to Window -> Devices , then once that window is opened at the bottom left click on the + and add a device?

Answer (score 0):

It took me an embarrassingly long time to figure out what I was doing wrong...

I had selected the wrong project to build.  That is: the selector to the left of the device selector was set to a Library that my project was using rather then the main project.

After selecting my main project my simulator started to start in the normal fashion.